# What is the fastest way to do I/O in Python?

Tags: python, performance, input, io

Like those programming challenges, right now I do the following:

For a single variable:

```
x = int(sys.stdin.readline())
```

for many variables

```
A, B, C = map(int,sys.stdin.readline().split())
```

Is this optimal or are there faster ways?

Comment: For most use cases, Python normal readline() is sufficient. You can try wrapping it in generator for iterations, which is built-in for file IO. I don't know if there is a generic 'optimal' for all use cases. Byte-wise input is possible, but not necessarily faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you have numpy available, the numpy loading functions are very fast. For example:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> s = '1\n2\n3\n4\n'
>>> data = numpy.fromstring(s, dtype=int, sep='\n')
>>> data
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

This example loads from a string, but you can also load directly from an open file using [numpy.fromfile](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html#numpy.fromfile).

Answer (score 0):

Python's sys library has 2 file objects **stdin** and **stdout** connected with **STDIN** and **STOUT**. **stdin** file object has **readline()** and **readlines()** methods & **stdou**t file object has **write()** method. We can use these methods for fast I/O in Python.

visit [here](https://algocoding.wordpress.com/2015/04/23/fast-io-methods-for-competitive-programming/)